# How can I make my pgfplots ylabel multiline?

Tags: pgfplots

My pgfplots ylabel text is too long and looks strange. Can I make it multiline?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

The `ylabel` can be adjusted like other nodes. The key you can use for this is `ylabel syle={<options>}`.

To make it multiline, you can either just provide a text alignment option, using `align=<center/left/right/justify>`, and then insert the line breaks manually with `\\`.

The second option is to provide a text width that the text should keep to, using `text width=<width>`, and it will automatically wrap around. By default, the text will be left aligned, but you can use the `align` key here, too.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=6cm,
ylabel style={align=center}, ylabel=A very long\\long\\text as a label,
xlabel style={text width=2.5cm}, xlabel=This is a long xlabel]
\addplot {x^2};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: pgfplots plot with multiline labels]

Comment: @Jake Did anything change since you posted your answer? I get an error-message saying: "I do not know the key '/tikz/align' and I am going to ignore it."

Comment: @John: That sounds like you're using a very old version of TikZ. The current version is 2.1, you're probably using 2.0 (which is several years old).

Comment: @Jake This is odd because I downloaded TeXShop (Version 2.47) a couple of month ago. Why should the package include an outdated distribution?

Comment: @John: The Linux distribution Ubuntu still ships with TeX Live 2009 (for compatibility reasons, I believe). I don't know what the situation is on Macs. What TeX distribution are you using? And, more importantly, what version of TikZ? You can check your TikZ version by including the command `\pgfversion` in a test document, which will print the version number in the output.

Comment: @Jake: I got the following output when including `\pgfversion` and `\pdftexbanner` into a test-tex: "TikZ Version: 2.0" and "This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-1.40.11-2.2 (TeX Live 2010) kpathsea version 6.0.0".

Comment: @John: Okay, so you've got an outdated version of TeX Live and TikZ. The best thing to do what probably be to install TeX Live 2012. Alternatively, you could just update the TikZ package.