# Multi-line nodes/annotations in pgfplot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, graphs

It would be great if I could get the annotation in the graph depicted below on two lines, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Presently, I have:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
            xlabel={$d_x = w^T_x-w^G_x$},
            ylabel={$s_x = e^{-\frac{d_x^2}{2\sigma^2_x}}$},
        ]
    \addplot+[
                domain=0:600,
                smooth,
            ]{exp(-x^2/(2*266.72^2))};
    \node[coordinate,pin=-90:{$d_x = 100, s_x = 0.932$}] at (axis cs:100,0.932) {};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: Graph with annotation on single line]

Looking at [a similar question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16213/how-can-i-make-my-pgfplots-ylabel-multiline), I've tried changing the `\node` to:

```
\node[coordinate,pin=-90:{$d_x = 100$\\$s_x = 0.932$}] at (axis cs:100,0.932) {};
```

This produces the following error:

> There's no line here to end

I've also tried replacing `\node` with a `\draw`:

```
\draw
        (axis cs:100,0)
    |-  (axis cs:0,0.8)
    node[near start,left]{$d_y = 100$\\$s_x = 0.932$};
```

This, too, doesn't seem to want to compile:

> Something's wrong; perhaps a missing \item

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to set the `align` option in order to get the `\\` to work. Try

```
\node[coordinate, pin={[align=left]-90:{$d_x = 100$,\\$s_x = 0.932$}}]
      at (axis cs:100,0.932) {};
```

(where you can also choose `align=center` or whatever if you prefer. Note the extra set of curly braces after `pin=`.)

Comment: Fantastic, that worked out exactly as I was hoping!