# multi line math in pgfplots labels

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, amsmath

Quick and maybe easy question, did some research on my own but didn't lead anywhere...
Is there a way to use a `split` or `multline` environment inside a pgfplot label? Maybe ditching the label altogether and replacing it with a `minipage` tikz `node`?

Comment: Like this: [How can I make my pgfplots ylabel multiline?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/16213)

Comment: at a first glance I don't think that would work with math, unless maybe using one `$ ... $` for each line, but I'd like to have a full alignable amsmath environment as a label

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `aligned`, `gathered` or `multlined`. The latter requires `mathtools`, thw two former are also in plain `amsmath`. These can be used in inline math.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots,mathtools}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
xlabel={$\begin{aligned}a &= b \\ &= c\end{aligned}$},
ylabel={$\begin{multlined}a + b + c\\ + d + e + f\end{multlined}$}]
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

That said, if you add `xlabel style={text width=7cm}` you can also use `align` and similar directly. By putting a `minipage` in the `xlabel` you don't need to set the `text width`. E.g.

```
xlabel={%
\begin{minipage}{7cm}
\begin{align}
a &= b \\
  &= c
\end{align}
\end{minipage}}
```

The result is kind of ridiculous of course.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots,mathtools}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
xlabel style={text width=7cm,yshift=\abovedisplayskip},
xlabel={%
\begin{align}
a &= b \\
  &= c
\end{align}
}]
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```