# Two y-axis graph problem with ylabel and legend - PGFplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, bar-chart, legend, axis

I have problems with using a two y-axis graph.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        axis y line*=right,
        ymin=0, ymax=300,
        ylabel style={align=center},
        ylabel={Very very very very very very long ylabel\\with a line break},
        width=0.9\linewidth,
        height=8cm,
        ymajorgrids,
        xtick ={1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12},
        compat=newest,
        ybar
    ]

    \addplot[bar width=5 pt, draw=blue, fill=blue!10] coordinates{
        (1,96)(2,114.9)(3,169.7)(4,182.1)(5,217.4)(6,238.7)(7,248.5)(8,242.3)(9,202.7)(10,147.2)(11,94.4)(12,81.8)
    };
    \label{C}

    \addplot[bar width=5 pt, draw=red, fill=red!10] coordinates{
        (1,88)(2,103)(3,171)(4,180)(5,199)(6,220)(7,250)(8,202)(9,166)(10,163)(11,140)(12,94)
    };
    \label{D}
\end{axis}

\begin{axis}[
    axis y line*=left,
    ymin=0, ymax=30,
    xtick ={1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12},
    xticklabels={},
    ylabel=ylabel1,
    width=0.9\linewidth,
    height=8cm,
    compat=newest,
    legend style={at={(0,1)},anchor=north west},
]

    \addplot+[mark=none, smooth, draw=blue, thick] coordinates{
        (1,3.1)(2,3.3)(3,5.4)(4,7.4)(5,11.0)(6,14.1)(7,15.8)(8,15.7)(9,12.9)(10,10.4)(11,6.1)(12,3.8)
    };
    \addlegendentry{A}

    \addplot+[mark=none, smooth, draw=red, thick] coordinates{
      (1,10.1)(2,11.7)(3,15.1)(4,17.3)(5,21.2)(6,24.5)(7,26.9)(8,27.1)(9,24.0)(10,19.4)(11,13.7)(12,10.5)
    };
    \addlegendentry{B}
    \addlegendimage{/pgfplots/refstyle=C,ybar, ybar legend}\addlegendentry{C}
    \addlegendimage{/pgfplots/refstyle=D,ybar, ybar legend}\addlegendentry{D}
\end{axis}
```

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

[image]

The first problem is that I can't perform line break with `ylabel` even though I indicated that I want a centered alignment (as stated [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16213/how-can-i-make-my-pgfplots-ylabel-multiline)).

The second problem is : how to center or right align the symbols (not the legend entries) in the legend ?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: The first problem is because you add `compat=newest` inside the axis. If you set it outside the axis, the problem disappears.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat, I need to work on my speed skill ^^.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue with the `ylabel` is because of the `compat=newest` inside the axis. If you move it out, it disappears. It suffices to move it before `ylabel style` but I think moving it out is cleaner. As for centering the legend pictures I have no better solution than redefining the corresponding `legend image code`. (Of course, you can do that locally if needed.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest,
/pgfplots/ybar legend/.style={
/pgfplots/legend image code/.code={
\draw [##1,/tikz/.cd,bar width=3pt,yshift=-0.2em,bar shift=0pt]
plot coordinates {(0.5em,0.8em) (0.5em+2*\pgfplotbarwidth,0.6em)}; },
}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        axis y line*=right,
        ymin=0, ymax=300,
        ylabel style={align=center},
        ylabel={Very very very very very very long ylabel\\with a line break},
        width=0.9\linewidth,
        height=8cm,
        ymajorgrids,
        xtick ={1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12},
        ybar
    ]
    \addplot[bar width=5 pt, draw=blue, fill=blue!10] coordinates{
        (1,96)(2,114.9)(3,169.7)(4,182.1)(5,217.4)(6,238.7)(7,248.5)(8,242.3)(9,202.7)(10,147.2)(11,94.4)(12,81.8)
    };
    \label{C}

    \addplot[bar width=5 pt, draw=red, fill=red!10] coordinates{
        (1,88)(2,103)(3,171)(4,180)(5,199)(6,220)(7,250)(8,202)(9,166)(10,163)(11,140)(12,94)
    };
    \label{D}
\end{axis}

\begin{axis}[
    axis y line*=left,
    ymin=0, ymax=30,
    xtick ={1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12},
    xticklabels={},
    ylabel=ylabel1,
    width=0.9\linewidth,
    height=8cm,
    legend style={at={(0,1)},anchor=north west},
]

    \addplot+[mark=none, smooth, draw=blue, thick] coordinates{
        (1,3.1)(2,3.3)(3,5.4)(4,7.4)(5,11.0)(6,14.1)(7,15.8)(8,15.7)(9,12.9)(10,10.4)(11,6.1)(12,3.8)
    };
    \addlegendentry{A}

    \addplot+[mark=none, smooth, draw=red, thick] coordinates{
      (1,10.1)(2,11.7)(3,15.1)(4,17.3)(5,21.2)(6,24.5)(7,26.9)(8,27.1)(9,24.0)(10,19.4)(11,13.7)(12,10.5)
    };
    \addlegendentry{B}
    \addlegendimage{/pgfplots/refstyle=C,ybar, ybar legend}\addlegendentry{C}
    \addlegendimage{/pgfplots/refstyle=D,ybar, ybar legend}\addlegendentry{D}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]