# Is there a way to make a gradient in a tikz plot that is y dependent?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, gradient

I am using pgfplots and tikz (with \begin(axis) ... \end(axis) ) to make a plot from somo data and I was wondering if it is possible to make a gradient in the plot that is dependent with the y axis, just like this:

[image]

Comment: Since the average gradiient is zero, you probably want a new y axis to overlap the ranges.  You can overlap two plots with one y axis on the left and one on the right.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/538789/two-y-axis-graph-problem-with-ylabel-and-legend-pgfplots for example.

Comment: With a continuous plot, this would be simple. But you are using a discrete plot that consists of lines that connect coordinates. I only can think of using `tikzfadingfrompicture`, but this is probably a bit too complicated here.

Comment: One could probably add more coordinates so that the single segments become reasonably small. I think this would be easier than to apply a gradient to every segment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are probably easier ways to achieve this, but you could create a fading from the plot and apply it to a rectangle filled with the gradient:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots,pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18} 

\usetikzlibrary{fadings, fit}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[tick style={transparent!100}]

\addplot[
        transparent!0,
        line width=2pt
    ] coordinates {(0,0) (1,1) (2,0.5) (3,1.5) (4,0)};

\end{axis}

\begin{tikzfadingfrompicture}[name=plot fading]
\begin{scope}[local bounding box=plot bbox]
\begin{axis}[tick style={transparent!100}]

\addplot[
        transparent!0,
        line width=2pt
    ] coordinates {(0,0) (1,1) (2,0.5) (3,1.5) (4,0)};

\end{axis}
\end{scope}
\end{tikzfadingfrompicture}

\fill[top color=blue, bottom color=cyan, path fading=plot fading, fit fading=false, fading transform={shift={(plot bbox.center)}}] 
    (plot bbox.north west) rectangle (plot bbox.south east);
    
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]